# Find the longest series of the same elements in a list

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a task where I have a list. Lots of `F` letters or `I` letters. I have to find the longest series of `F` elements. And the index of it.

For example I have these in the list:

> F, F, F, I, I, I, F, F, F, F, I

In this case I have to get that the longest series are 4 elements and it starts on the 7th place. I did not really have any idea how to solve the task.

I tried it:

```
listt=["F","F","F","I","I","I","F","F","F","F","I"]

num = 0
biggest_num = 0

for i in range(len(listt)):
    if list[i] == "F":
        num = num + 1
    else: 
        biggest_num = num
        num = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def longest_substring(arr):
    len_substring = 0
    longest = 0
    idx = 0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if i > 0:
            if arr[i] != arr[i-1]:
                len_substring = 0

        len_substring += 1

        if len_substring > longest:
            longest = len_substring
            idx = i
    return longest, idx - longest + 2

l = ['F', 'F', 'F', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'I']
longest, idx = longest_substring(l)

print ("longest series have length: {}, and starts at place: {}".format(longest, idx ))
```

output:

```
longest series have length: 4, and starts at place: 7
```

Comment: fails for empty list

Comment: I make edit ...

Comment: need to fix this `longest series have length: 0, and starts at place: 2`

Comment: it is not necessary! if len(arr) is 0 it will not enter for loop

Answer (score 2):

Try `groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
l = ['F', 'F', 'F', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'I']
print(max([len(list(i)) for _, i in groupby(l)]))
```

Output:

```
4
```

Comment: !!....Nice...!!

Comment: @yatu Lol yeah, but if this is too complex for the OP i am not helping him as well lol.

Answer (score 1):

understandable  basic solution

```
def func(l):
    if len(l)==0:
        return 0
    res =[]
    tmp =[l[0]]
    for i in range(1,len(l)):
        if l[i]==l[i-1]:
            tmp.append(l[i])
        else:
            res.append(tmp)
            tmp=[l[i]]
    res.append(tmp)

    return max([len(i) for i in res])

l =['F', 'F', 'F', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'I']

sol = func(l)
print(sol)
```

output

```
4
```